# How to get both before and after updated records in azure data factory

Tags: azure, azure-functions, azure-sql-database, azure-data-factory

I had a scenario if a new record is updated, I need both before the update and currently updated value in azure data factory, and pass it to function app. Since CDC is not supported in Azure SQL I cannot get History records. Kindly suggest me to get better solution

Comment: No, we can't do that in Data Factory.

Comment: You need to write your own code for this scenario, then you can capture the data before and after. For reference https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/quickstart-create-data-factory-dot-net#create-a-pipeline-run

Comment: Hi @Raj Kumar, If my answer is helpful for you, hope you can accept it as answer( click on the check mark beside the answer to toggle it from greyed out to filled in.). This can be beneficial to other community members. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I'm afraid to say, data factory can't get the data both before the update and currently updated value. Data Factory is more focus on data transferring and some data conversion.

Maybe you need build your code and design a new logic to achieve that, before update the record, query first and store the data. Then update data and query again to get the current data.